# Moving Existing Directories to a new EBS Volume in AWS (Red Hat)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, partitioning, rhel

I have an EC2 instance with a 20GB root volume. I attached an additional 200GB volume for partitioning to comply with DISA/NIST 800-53 STIG by creating separate partitions for directories such as `/home`, `/var`, and `/tmp`, as well as others required by company guidelines. Using **Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.5**. I rarely ever do this and haven't done it for years so I'm willing to accept stupid solutions.

I've followed multiple tutorials using various methods and get the same result each time. The short (from my understanding), the OS cannot access certain files/directories on these newly mounted partitions.

Example: When I mount say `/var/log/audit`, the audit daemon will fail.
"Job for auditd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See..."
`systemctl status auditd` says "Failed to start Security Auditing Service". I am also unable to login via public key when I mount /home but these types of problems go away when I unmount the new partitions. `journalctl -xe` reveals "Could not open dir /var/log/audit (Permission denied).

Permission for each dir is:
drwxr-xr-x root root /var
drwxr-xr-x root root /var/log
drws------ root root /var/log/audit

Which is consistent with the base OS image, which DOES work when the partition isn't mounted.

What I did:
-Create EC2 with 2 volumes (EBS)
-Partitioned the new volume `/dev/xvdb`
-Formatted partition to extf
-Create `/etc/fstab` entries for the partitions
-Mounted partitions to a temp place in `/mnt` then copied the contents using `rsync -av <source> <dest>`
-Unmounted the new partitions and updated `fstab` to reflect actual mount locations, e.g. `/var/log/audit`

I've tried:
-Variations such as different disk utilities (e.g. fdisk, parted)
-Using different partition schemes (GPT, DOS [default], Windows basic [default for the root volume, not sure why], etc.)
-Using the root volume from an EC2, detaching, attaching to other instance as a 2nd volume, and only repartitioning

Ownership, permissions, and directory structures are exactly the same, as far as I can tell, between the original directory and the directory created on the new partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds stupid but did you try restarting instance after new mounts?

The reason why I suggest this is because linux caches dir/file path to inode mapping. When you change mount, I am not sure if cache is invalidated. And that can possibly the reason for errors.

Also, though it is Ubuntu have a look at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: I tried and no luck. The mentioned tutorial is pretty much what I did. I'm not sure if Amazon EC2 functions differently in a way that affects this more. Also I don't think this should affect it but it's AWS but not their public service so many non-primary features aren't included. EC2 seems to function as normal though.